# website does not work without www

Tags: iis, iis-8, windows-server-2012

I am working on iis8 for the first time, but my website is php, but i dont think the issue is within php, because:

if i enter: http://mywebsite.com/image.jpg
it does not load the image, just timed out page.

but if i enter: http://www.mywebsite.com/image.jpg
it works fine.

also, i can ping mywebsite.com but not www.mywebsite.com

the answer might be very simple, so kindly dont give me negative votes :)

Comment: Do you have the A record on DNS properly configured?

Comment: This is a question for http://serverfault.com, not SO. This is server and DNS administration, not programming.

Comment: Since you can ping one and not the other, `mywebsite.com` simply resolves to another host than `www.mywebsite.com`. It's not an IIS issue, it's DNS.

Comment: most likely its the right answer, i am waiting to have access to dns server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make another alias in your DNS server.

Answer (score 9):

Have you setup a binding for "mywebsite.com" in addition to "www.mywebsite.com"?

To setup a binding, select your website in ISS, select "Bindings" from the "Actions" menu (or right click and choose "Edit Bindings".  Then click "Add" to setup the additional binding.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder It looks like a perfectly good answer to me, he just needs to set up bindings for both versions of the site's address.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: The original answer was just the initial question. *Now*, it resembles an answer.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder tried it but nothing has changed, so its dns thing, and i dont have access to that part :(